# limit of $x \log y$ at $ (0,0)$

Tags: limits

What is the limit of the function $x \log y $ at $(0,0)$? I believe the limit doesn't exist. But wolframalpha.com says the limit is 0.

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit[+x+log%28y%29++%2C+x-%3E0%2C+y-%3E+0+]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%5B%20x%20log%28y%29%20%20,%20x-%3E0,%20y-%3E%200%20%5D)
[image]

Comment: What definition of limit are you using?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: The normal one, the limit of a 2-variable function. Not the iterated limit.

Comment: Wolframalpha can report the limit doesn't exist for $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$, but get it wrong for this one.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in being suspicious. Approach $(0,0)$ along the path $y=e^{-1/x}$. The limit along this path is $-1$. Modify to taste.

Comment: Is this really a valid path? $y = e^{-1/x}$ doesn't contain the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Adriano: You are right, it doesn't contain $(0,0)$.  But as $x\to 0^+$, $e^{-1/x}\to 0$. That is what matters.

Comment: Along the path y=x, the limit is 0.